# How can I get Git to ignore/drop files I have deleted or that are only file-system artifacts (ending in ~)?

Tags: linux, git

I would like my git repository to show only files that currently exist in the directory. In particular, I just pushed my git project to a remote repository on github.com, and now it's showing all sorts of deleted files that I don't have or want in my directory anymore. It's also showing all sorts of remnants from past editing, including files ending in `~`. How can I get rid of both previously deleted files that I don't want to see anymore and all files ending in `~`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to delete files in a repository is using the `git rm` command. This command, additionally to removing the file from the filesystem, tells the git repository to not handle it anymore. If you just deleted it from the filesystem and commited & pushed it, it will still be available on the remote repository.

Analogously, there is a `git mv` command if you ever need to rename some file.

To ignore some files or extensions, you can simply create a `.gitignore` file in the top repository directory and include any filename, directory or even pattern you want to ignore (one per line).

Example of valid entries:

```
myfile.c
mydirectory/
*~
```

Doing this, Git will ignore any entry and even if you run `git add *`, any matching filename, directory or pattern matching entry will not be commited.